# How to filter queryset on calculated field provided by `extra` call in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my django models:

```
class Author (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    removed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Image (models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    width  = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Basically, i need to select each author who is not removed and who has 5 or less images with height equal to 100.

I use MySQL, and here is version info:

> mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.67

Naturally, it would look like this:

```
Author.objects.filter(removed=False).extra(select={
    'imgcount': """SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM ormtest_image 
                   WHERE height=100 AND 
                         ormtest_image.author_id=ormtest_author.id"""
}).filter(imgcount__lte=5)
```

It does not work: "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'imgcount' into field. Choices are: id, image, name, removed"

OK, let's try where argument of extra method:

```
Author.objects.filter(removed=False).extra(select={
    'imgcount': """SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM ormtest_image 
                   WHERE height=100 AND 
                         ormtest_image.author_id=ormtest_author.id"""
}, where=['imgcount <= 5'])
```

It does not work as well: "OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'imgcount' in 'where clause'")", since to filter data on calculated field in MySQL you have to use HAVING clause.

Any ideas?

I tested this with Django 1.1 and latest version from trunk.

So far, i use this hack:

```
Author.objects.filter(removed=False).extra(select={
    'imgcount': """SELECT COUNT(*) 
                   FROM ormtest_image 
                   WHERE height=100 AND 
                         ormtest_image.author_id=ormtest_author.id"""
}, where=['1 HAVING imgcount <=5'])
```

P.S. YAML fixture:

```
---
- model: ormtest.author
  pk: 1
  fields:
      name: 'Author #1'
      removed: 0
- model: ormtest.author
  pk: 2
  fields:
      name: 'Author #2'
      removed: 0
- model: ormtest.author
  pk: 3
  fields:
      name: 'Author #3'
      removed: 1
- model: ormtest.image
  pk: 1
  fields:
      author: 1
      name: 'Image #1'
      height: 100
      width: 100
- model: ormtest.image
  pk: 2
  fields:
      author: 1
      name: 'Image #2'
      height: 150
      width: 150
- model: ormtest.image
  pk: 3
  fields:
      author: 2
      name: 'Image #3'
      height: 150
      width: 100
- model: ormtest.image
  pk: 4
  fields:
      author: 2
      name: 'Image #4'
      height: 150
      width: 150
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, untested because I don't have your data - how about this:

```
Author.objects.filter(removed=False).select_related('image').filter(image__height=100).annotate(count_of_images=Count('image')).filter(count_of_images__lte=5)
```

Edit:

That took you almost there. The problem is related to the outer join... I think this is the final version that should do it for you:

```
Author.objects.filter(removed=False).select_related('image').filter(Q(image__height=100) | Q(image__height__isnull=True)).annotate(count_of_images=Count('image')).filter(count_of_images__lte=5)
```

That `Q(image__height=100) | Q(image__height__isnull=True)` in there is the trick. It will get either Authors that have images with a height of 100 ***OR*** authors that have an image height of null (meaning that they don't have images associated).

PS. Thanks for the question... It was actually more challenging than I originally thought and I learned some cool tricks in the process of trying to test it!

---

Ouch... I did test my last solution with sqlite3. I don't have a MySQL instance to use for testing... :-(

Let me ponder an alternative.

But - yes - if it works in sqlite it should work in MySQL; I would report it as a bug.

Comment: well, i need to select all authors from database who owns 5 or less images with height equal to 100px exactly. With annotation, i will receive all authors from database which is not what i need (in performance reason)

Comment: btw, with your solution still receiving:
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'imgcount' in 'where clause'")

Comment: And edited once more because I forgot the count of images... :-)

Comment: And edited once more because I forgot the <= 5. I think now it is done. Sorry about that...

Comment: however, this solution eliminates all authors who has 0 images with height = 100...

Comment: your latest statement generates this SQL:

SELECT ormtest_author.*, 
       COUNT(`ormtest_image`.`id`) AS `count_of_images` 
FROM `ormtest_author` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ormtest_image` 
ON (`ormtest_author`.`id` = `ormtest_image`.`author_id`) 
WHERE 
   (`ormtest_author`.`removed` = False  AND
    `ormtest_image`.`height` = 100 ) 
GROUP BY `ormtest_author`.`id` 
HAVING COUNT(`ormtest_image`.`id`) <= 5  
ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 21

you see, problem in having `ormtest_image`.`height` = 100 in WHERE clause...

Comment: thank you man for your help! 

but a.. still with your latest solution i am receiving only author, who does has at least 1 image with height=100.

i edited the question, added fixture i use.

btw, i tested my second solution from the question (with where=['imgcount <= 5']) with sqlite3, it works just perfectly. So, main problem here is MySQL. Probably, i need to report a bug to Django project.

Comment: please make any small change (formatting) to your answer, i accidentally clicked on the vote number and it removed my vote!

Comment: Could you post here the SQL generated for MySQL?

Comment: here is it: 

SELECT `ormtest_author`.`id`, `ormtest_author`.`name`, `ormtest_author`.`removed`, COUNT(`ormtest_image`.`id`) AS `count_of_images` FROM `ormtest_author` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ormtest_image` ON (`ormtest_author`.`id` = `ormtest_image`.`author_id`) WHERE (`ormtest_author`.`removed` = False  AND (`ormtest_image`.`height` = 100  OR `ormtest_image`.`height` IS NULL)) GROUP BY `ormtest_author`.`id` HAVING COUNT(`ormtest_image`.`id`) <= 5  ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 21

Comment: it is SQL generated by your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're not using the count value except to filter for those authors where it is greater than 1. If so, you can do this entirely in ORM code with a simple query:

```
Author.objects.filter(removed=False, image__height__gte=100)
```

Comment: Wait... But isn't the extra() call also adding the imgcount field to the queryset? I assumed that he wanted that. If the only reason he was doing the extra was to further limit the queryset, than your solution is obviously the correct one.

Comment: sorry, i provided with not very good example. In real project, i need to get Authors who owns 5 or less "images with height equal to 100"